# How can I read a file with paramiko?

Tags: python, paramiko

I made some script using `paramiko`.
My script works using `ssh` connection, output file, and print out file.

When i run script, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "test.py", line 31, in 
>           print line
>       ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

My script,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

### Netapp C-Mode Connection and command excute
import paramiko
import sys
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

from paramiko import AutoAddPolicy

sip = raw_input('input IP.\n')
sid = raw_input('input ID.\n')
spass = raw_input('input PASS.\n')

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=sip, username=sid, password=spass)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('hostname')
sys.stdout=open("c_host.txt","w")
print (stdout.read()).strip()
sys.stdout.close()

client.close()

f = open("c_host.txt")
for line in f:
        print (line)
```

Any thoughts why this error occurs based on my script?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('cat /path/to/file')`
`StringIO(stdout.read().decode())` to read it as a file; that's useful sometimes if you want to read that file as an array instead of an explicit string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default target for `print` is `sys.stdout`, which you redirected and closed 4 lines above the attempted `print`. Instead of redirecting `sys.stdout` just tell `print` what's your desired target (or use the file's `write` method):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('hostname')
target_f = open("c_host.txt", "w")
print(stdout.read().strip(), file=target_f)
target_f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. But your script occurred error.   File "9.brocade.py", line 26
    print(stdout.read(), file=target_f)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're probably using python 2, so replace this line with: `target_f.write(stdout.read())`

Comment: Please provide your current complete code and error message